# Json binding in an array of checkboxes

Tags: arrays, json, angular

I have an array of checkboxes coming from a collection.

See below:

```
<div class="form-group">
    Select days in a week :
    <td class="even" *ngFor="let item of dayList">
    <input value="{{item.check}}" type="checkbox" checked="item.check" formControlName = "selectedDays">  {{item}}
   </div>
```

formControlName I am set as selectedDays.

I need to generate JSON object for the selected checkbox values.

Currently, i am getting boolean value in selectedDays. But I am supposed to get an array of checked values in an array inside JSON object.

> this.dayList  =  ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue','Wed',"Thu","Fri","Sat"];

JSON Object looks like below, please note the value of selectedDays, it is supposed to be "Sun, Mon" based on selection, but it is showing as true.

```
 Object
    date
    :
    "2"
    day
    :
    "Mon"
    hour
    :
    "3"
    minute
    :
    "3"
    schedulerjobtype
    :
    "Daily"
    selectedDays
    :
    true
    useCase
    :
    "UC 2"
    zone
    :
    "Zone 3"
```

How can I implement this?

Comment: any idea why downvoted?

Comment: can you post dayList array as well???

Comment: updated question

Answer (score 0):

Use [(ngModel)] in place of value

```
 <input [(ngModel)]="item.check" type="checkbox" checked="item.check" formControlName = "selectedDays">
```

Comment: this is showing the checkboxes now, but still, the JSON object value shows true, i am expecting array or comma separated values.